# Fix content than scroll when user is near the end of the page

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

Bit of a puzzler here.

I have a div that has I want to display on screen at all times. I use the following CSS:

```
<style>
    .f {position: fixed;
     bottom:0px
     align:center;
     }
</style>
```

I'm trying to figure how to keep it fixed to the bottom of the screen until 200px from the end I want it to scroll with the page then so it will be 200px from the bottom when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: create a **fiddle** of what you are expecting and post some `html` too!

Comment: Try look here: https://css-tricks.com/scroll-fix-content/

Comment: I have edited my answer quite a few times, but this time there should be no error and a working jsfiddle example. Its quite hard to explain the math we do in short words. Feel free to ask, if something is not as clear as it should be!

Answer (score 0):

Lets do a basic build up:

```
<div id="content">Content to be scrolled as Wrapper </div>
<div id="mydiv" class="fixed"> Div that should be fixed </div>
<div id="end"> Everything after the fixed div </div>
```

We quickly fix your div at the bottom using the class `.fixed` so that we can use `.addClass('fixed')` and `.removeClass('fixed')` to toggle some css attributes.

```
.fixed {
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0;
}
```

So there is this `.scrollTop` function, that allows us to scroll a certain amount of pixels from the top to the bottom. That is already exactly what you need. The trick is to know how many pixels from the top the fixed element should start to scroll with the content.

Lets do some jQuery to find out:

```
// Create function to add/remove Class if .scrollTop
$.fn.followTo = function (pos) {
    var $this = this,
        $window = $(window);

    $window.scroll(function (e) {
        if ($window.scrollTop() < pos) {
            $this.addClass('fixed');
        } else {
            $this.removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
};

var $height_content = $('#content').outerHeight(); //get height of content
var $height_div = $('#mydiv').outerHeight(); //get height of fixed div
var $height_viewport = $(window).height(); //get height of viewport
var $fixed_till = ($height_content + $height_div - $height_viewport);

// Use function created above like so:
// $('selector').followTo( /* height from top in px */ );
$('#mydiv').followTo($fixed_till);
```

Check the **[DEMO ON JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/marianrick/8kLtmf2s/)**